# How to block a Jenkins Job running once a minute for a specific date and time

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job from triggered every minute. But, I want to stop for a specific date and time.

[Freestyle Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2541.png)

[Configuration Triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSpw0.png)

I want you to help, please.

Comment: Can you please give more details about your requirement? like give an example of what specific date and time you would like to skip?

Comment: What do you want to stop? Stop running it at a specific date/time? Or only running it at a specific date/time? Also, please provide some code instead of pictures, it's better for help. By the way, running a job every minute is risky as you have to be sure your job last less than 1 min.

Comment: Example;
- Job is triggered every minutes of 7/24 on Jenkins. Job complete in less than 1 minute. Checking server standing up/down.
- In some cases, the server needs to be shut down. I know when the server will shut down and turn on. 
       Shut Down: 07.04.2021 14:00
       Turn On: 07.04.2021 15:00
- Job should not be triggered during these hours on Jenkins. Then re-trigger should continue.
-Now, job is trigger once a minute on Jenkins. But I can't stop.